# Changing variable in quotes to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

Sorry that my title isn't very clear - didn't really know what else to call this.

Basically what I want to do is have a variable that is

```
"authData."+service+".displayName";
```

And turn that into

```
authData.theValueGivenToService.displayName;
```

Any idea on how to do that?

(I'm working with JavaScript/JQuery by the way - I should have mentioned that earlier)

Comment: The question is not really clear to me, what's your goal?

Comment: Yeah, sorry I hadn't realized this had already been asked (I wasn't able to find anything for it). Should I just delete this one now?

Comment: @Satpal I was just going to use it as shorthand for authData[service].displayName but I now realize that that's pointless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to access a property of object then do:

```
displayName = authData[service].displayName;
```

Comment: A suggestion, Don't start answer with `if`, it shows you are making a guess better leave a comment for clarification.

Comment: @Satpal that is okay, but my `if` was depicting that I am pretty sure what OP is asking but the way OP has choses is probably not the best way to write it down. But yes your suggestion, i got it. :)

Comment: @void It tells me "I can accept an answer in 5 minutes". I'm somewhat new here, so I have no idea why, but I'll mark it as answer when it lets me. Thank you so much for your help! :)